# Positioning div to the right with an undefined width

Tags: javascript, html, css, responsive-design, resize

I'm going to have trouble explaining what I mean but bear with me. First here's my fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/jmajnqej/5/ (updated by Aziz)

```
#freelancewrapper {
width: 100%;
max-width: 1000px;
height: 440px;
background-color: #9D9D9D;
position: absolute;
}
```

I'm trying to get freelancewrapper to hug the right side of the screen with no padding. It needs to stay connected to the very right side of the screen no matter what width the window is. To make it more complicated it's parent div contentwrapper has to stay where it is with the same width and margins.

here is a representation of two screen sizes to show what I mean. https://i.stack.imgur.com/V2XxM.jpg

**Update:** I didn't realize it at the time but this is a two part question. Positioning it was easy but getting the right correct width property is not. Here's my question for that [Trouble defining width of a responsive div](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35469835/trouble-defining-width-of-a-responsive-div).

Comment: You'd need to use positioning for that. An image of the desired result would probably be useful. This feels like an XY Problem

Comment: I've updated the fiddle as well as upload a couple of pictures :).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you have to do is add the following CSS properties to your element:

```
  position: absolute;
  right:0;
```

[jsFiddle fork](https://jsfiddle.net/azizn/wcjxwo4e/)

If you want the div to remain attached to the screen when scrolling, you can replace `absolute` with `fixed`.

Keep in mind that `position: absolute` works relative to the first parent tag with a `position:relative`. by default, that tag would be the `body`.

Also an important thing to keep in mind is that when an element is absolutely positioned, it will lose its space in the layout and hover over all elements.

Comment: Thanks for the help, however this doesn't keep the margin-left: constant like I'm trying. I'll upload a picture to further show what I mean.

Comment: yes, an element with absolute positioning does not affect the layout and loses its space. You can either create a placeholder div that is not absolutely positioned with the margins you want OR you can try applying margins to other elements...

Comment: P.S you may consider `float:right` as well instead of positioning

Comment: Thanks man, I'm halfway there. Used absolute positioning with float right. I'm just struggling with the width property now. I can't get it to minimize properly or increase in width to constantly hug the right of the screen. Any ideas? :)

Comment: Don't use float with absolute positioning... as for width, play with the percentages or apply a fixed width and change it with media queries

Comment: Right I ditched the float right, silly me :p ... I've been at this for a long time man. I'm beginning to think it's not possible without javascript, thing is I'm terrible at javascript :/.

Comment: Well, the solutions here answer your initial question about making a div attached to a side of the viewport, perhaps be more clear about what you need done or ask a new questions with new problems you face. There is a great difference between the simple jsFiddle demo and the photos you provided

Comment: I didn't intend on having a two part question but that's how it turned out :p ... I've changed the title and updated the question. Do you still suggest asking a new question, I try not to flood the question feed.

Answer (score 1):

I can't tell you the exact value you should need to achieve the desired result. What i would advice for trying to make your styling "responsive" is to start 1. from a mobile first approach(easier to up the screen size then downsizing).

To further answer your question try using relative units. your width for example is 100% this is relative. But instead of pixels try using **em**.

every ~16 px(not precise) is 1.0 **em**.

furthermore you can use **position: absolute;**

good luck further.

Comment: Thanks for the general tips. I've been reading that a lot lately. Personally I barely use my phone to browse the web...I guess I have to get with the trend :p. I've uploaded some pictures if you wish to see what I mean by my question.

Answer (score 0):

Like Paulie_D said you can use position

**CSS**

```
.contentwrapper {
    width: calc(100% - 190px);
    max-width: 1160px;
    margin-top: 50px;
    margin-left: 40px;
    position: absolute;
    right:0;
}
```

**[DEMO HERE](https://jsfiddle.net/luispa/jmajnqej/1/)**

Comment: Thanks for the input I should have mentioned the contentwrapper has to remain where it is with the current width. I'll upload a picture to show what I mean as I'm struggling to explain.

Answer (score 0):

you can use negative right margin on `<div class='contentwrapper'>`

```
.contentwrapper{
    margin-right: -48px;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/linkers/jmajnqej/3/

Comment: Not a bad idea. I forgot to mention contentwrapper has to remain where it is, sorry I've updated my question. I've also added some pictures to further explain what I mean. :)