# Trouble defining width of a responsive div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, responsive-design

I'm going to have trouble explaining what I mean but bear with me. First here's my fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/jmajnqej/20/

```
#freelancewrapper {
width: calc(100% - 238px);
height: 440px;
background-color: #9D9D9D;
position: absolute;
right: 0;
}
```

I'm trying to get #freelancwrapper which is positioned inside .contentwrapper to hug the left of the .contentwrapper but at the same time have a greater width which extends to touch the right side of the viewport.

(note: the fiddle currently works for roughly under 1400-1500px viewport width but at sizes larger than that the freelancewrapper extends wider than the parent div).

If there is confusing here hopefully my pictures further explain.
 https://i.stack.imgur.com/QkwLB.jpg (two different screen sizes).

Any input is much appreciated.

Comment: Is requirement for right side of `.freelancewrapper` to a) remain within right side viewport ?; or b) extend beyond right side of viewport ?

Comment: To stay in the viewport, I'll update the question.

Comment: If I'm understanding the question correctly, I'd say your best bet is to get rid of the floats and use `position: absolute` on both the parent and the child, giving them both `right: 0`.  But I'm not entirely certain that I understand exactly what you're going for.

Comment: I tried giving it's parent absolute positioning in my actual project but it affects all of it's surrounds. Also I'm not 100% sure you understand what I'm trying to achieve. Sorry for the confusing question, it's a tough one to phrase.

Comment: You're fine.  I think @guest271314's answer might be more helpful

Comment: He's helped. Gotten me close still having trouble getting #freelancewrapper to hug the right of the viewport.

Comment: **Stop spamming trivial edits to your question**. This is completely unnecessary. This isn't the first time you've spammed a bunch of garbage edits at a question in an effort to bump it. If you don't have new, useful information to edit into your question, do not edit it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, this could be approached differently. `position:absolute` seemed like a good solution at the start but it requires a lot of maintenance because it makes the element lose its space in the layout and the margins do not collapse with others.

To simplify things, let's go to the basics. Consider the following sample:

```css
html, body {margin: 0;padding: 0;}

div {
  background:blue;
  height:100px;
  width:100px;
}

div div {
  background:red;
  height:50px;
  width:200px;
  color:#FFF;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div>200px wide red div</div>
</div>
100px wide blue div
```

As you can see, elements which are bigger than their parent/container are visible by default.

Now from my understanding, you wish to expand the red div to the right side of the screen while making sure the solution is responsive. In this case, what we really need to do is calculate the distance between our element's bonds (in this example, the blue container) and the viewport side.

Usually developers would resort to javascript to make these calculations, however, modern CSS3 enables us to do this natively using `calc()` expression with `vw` / `vh` viewport units.

### Calculated padding for expanding element to viewport side

This method requires that the expanded div get a width of `100%`. Please note that the content of this expanded div will not go outside the width of the parent. However, backgrounds will work as expected.

> `padding-right: calc((100vw - 100%) / 2);`

`100vw` is the viewport, `100%` is the parent's width (or max-width) divided by 2 will result in the space between the element and the viewport (one side)

```css
html, body {margin: 0;padding: 0; max-width:100%; overflow-x:hidden;} /* makes sure to prevent horizontal scrollbar */

.container {
  width:100px;
  background:blue;
  height:200px;
  margin:0 auto;
}

.expanded {
  color:#FFF;
  height:100px;
  background:red;
  width:100%; /* required for method to work */
  padding-right: calc((100vw - 100%) / 2);
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="expanded">I expand to the right side of viewport</div>
</div>
```

Also worth mentioning that I have applied `overflow-x:hidden` and `max-width:100%` to the body tag to make sure browsers do not show scrollbars if the calculation was not rounded (for consistency).

---

**This method is good because:**

- Does not break layout
- Responsive (even works with min/max width of parent)
- Simple code

**Drawbacks to consider:**

- Support for CSS `calc()`
- Support for viewport units
- Support for viewport unit calculations (does not work for old Safari browsers)
- No right padding (can be solved by wrapping other elements in another div)

---

And finally, here is a simple demo that shows the effect using the layout you have provided in the images: **[view on jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/azizn/1g1dw5j8/1/)**

```css
body {
  width:100%;
  max-width:100%;
  overflow-x:hidden;
}

.wrapper {
  width: 86%;
  max-width: 1350px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background: #EEE;
  position: relative;
}

.contentwrapper {
  height: 300px;
  
  /* another method based on width instead of right padding */
  /* width: 93vw; */
  /* max-width: calc(1350px + ((100vw - 1350px) / 2)); */
  
  width:100%;
  padding-right: calc((100vw - 100%) / 2);
}

/* ---------------------------- */
/* demo styling
/* ---------------------------- */

html,
body {
  background: #FFF;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

.contentwrapper {
  background: #7f6e60 url(http://i.imgur.com/yKbPM43.jpg) no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  margin-bottom:30px;
}

.content { padding: 1em; }

#freelancewrapper {
  color:#FFF;
  padding:1em 2em;
  height: 100%;
  position: relative;
}

#freelancewrapper p {
  background: rgba(255, 0, 45, 0.58);
  width:60%;
  height:60%;
  padding:1em;
  font-weight: bold;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -20px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<!-- main wrapper -->
<div class='wrapper'>

  <!-- some content at top -->
  <div class="content">
    <h3>Content above expanded div</h3>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ipsam nam ut incidunt odit ea blanditiis dicta alias, eaque iusto! Voluptatem eveniet modi dignissimos praesentium adipisci quibusdam laudantium ex ut fugiat.</p>
  </div>
  
  <!-- div that expands to end of viewport (right side) -->
  <div class='contentwrapper'>
    <section id='freelancewrapper'>
      <h1>Why hire a freelance designer?</h1>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Facere, hic inventore sunt harum nesciunt voluptatem deserunt assumenda tenetur. Explicabo, eligendi ipsum laboriosam porro nisi quos, qui, adipisci id veritatis necessitatibus ducimus dignissimos maiores nobis voluptates perspiciatis vero? Laborum fugiat itaque placeat, voluptatibus. Repellendus fuga, vel alias eos molestias.</p>
    </section>
  </div>
  
  <!-- more content below -->
  <div class="content">
    <h3>Content below expanded div</h3>
    <p>Temporibus possimus illo quis provident, illum perferendis maxime fugit tempora rem incidunt earum amet vitae atque est alias dolores totam architecto voluptatem voluptate, officiis deleniti enim accusantium laborum error. Fugiat.</p>
  </div>
  
</div>
```

Comment: Aziz has came to the rescue again. I was about to resort to my terrible javascript knowledge to fix this problem but you have done it simply. I knew there was a way...Thanks a ton man :).

Answer (score 1):

If requirement is to stretch `.freelancewrapper` horizontally to fill viewport , try setting `width` to `calc(100% - 174px)` , `overflow` to `hidden` , `text-overflow` to `ellipsis` , `right` to `calc(47px)` to maintain margin at right side of viewport

```
  #freelancewrapper {
    right:calc(47px);
    width: calc(100% - 174px);
    min-width:calc(47px);
    max-width: 1000px;
    height: 440px;
    background-color: #9D9D9D;
    position: absolute;
    overflow:hidden;
    text-overflow:ellipsis;
  }
```

jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/jmajnqej/15/

Comment: Close but not quite what I'm going for. As you increase the width of the viewport the margin-left to the contentwrapper changes. I'm trying to keep it as 0, like my fiddle. Thanks though.

Comment: @MarcusPorter Try setting `width: calc(100% - 190px);` , 
 `min-width: calc(70vw);` See https://jsfiddle.net/jmajnqej/8/

Comment: Little closer. I'm going to re do my images and try and re word my question to explain it better. It's a tough one to explain.

Comment: @MarcusPorter _"Little closer."_ ? Can you describe expected result ?

Comment: The left-margin between freelancewrapper and its parent need to be 0. give me a couple minutes to re-do my image examples.

Comment: Is requirement for `.freelancewrapper` to be contained within `.contentwrapper` ? , but still have width greater than `.contentwrapper` when viewport is resized to decrease `.contentwrapper` width to being not visible in viewport ? Question , expected results do not appear very clear ? The images are not that helpful; describing expected results would perhaps help other users provide an Answer

Comment: @MarcusPorter See updated post; removed `right:0px` . Left side of `.freelancewrapper` should remain fixed at same position as parent `.contentwrapper` element

Comment: I appreciate all the help man but the right side of freelancewrapper has to constantly be against the right side of the viewport. I'm thinking I may have to rethink the way I'm approaching this and get freelancwrapper to sit outside .contentwrapper somehow. It's a tough one.

Comment: we're getting close. I modified it even more https://jsfiddle.net/jmajnqej/16/ ... I'll continue to play around with it but as you can see once the viewport gets wider freelancwrapper extends out of the contentwrapper.

Comment: _"I modified it even more"_ ? How does https://jsfiddle.net/jmajnqej/15/ not return described expected results ?

Comment: it was hugging the right side of its parent div instead of the right side of the viewport.

Comment: I love how we're up to 17 and you haven't got frustrated and left yet thanks :p ... The max-width property was a mistake from the beginning, get rid of that and you will see it's having trouble hugging the left side of its parent div. we're so close.

Comment: @MarcusPorter Does updated jsfiddle return expected results ?

Comment: @MarcusPorter _"The max-width property was a mistake from the beginning, get rid of that and you will see it's having trouble hugging the left side of its parent div"_ ? Removed `max-width` , `.freelancewrapper` appear to remain fixed to left side parent container , here; see https://jsfiddle.net/jmajnqej/18/. Note also, `css` at updated Question is not original `css` from original Question

Comment: Try stretching the width of the viewport to around 1500px, the freelancewrapper extends out of its parent. Hopefully you see what I mean.

Comment: Do not currently have access to a screen having `width` over 1500px. This description should be at OP

Comment: Yes the problems only just came up within our last few attempts. I'll update it.

Comment: The 1500px portion was not within original Question. Perhaps ask another Question specific to that portion if original Question has been resolved by last updated jsfiddle ? Instead of continuing to update Question with new requirements ?

Comment: The original question did state it needed to constantly hug the left side of its parent. I have updated it anyhow.

Comment: I up voted your answer because you have been helpful. Still looking for a working solution so I can't accept an answer just yet. Thanks man :).

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if I got your question exactly: but if you just want to stick the #freelancewrapper to the right you need to do something like this:

```
#freelancewrapper {
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 1000px;
    height: 440px;
    background-color: #9D9D9D;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0; // this should do it
}
```

Comment: Thanks but this isn't the desired result I'm going for. I'm going to change my images and question to try and be more clear. As I said it's hard to explain. Thanks anyway.